I’ve been using LiveData to load items, ensuring that any changes in the dB trigger updates, but it's not working as expected
I have created the Simple Project for Item to be Listed in one fragment and to do CRUD operation in another Fragment . I have used Live data ,Viewmodel and Sql lite instead to Room.
According to the Definition of Live Data :
"Instead of updating the UI every time the app data changes, your observer can update the UI every time there's a change."
But its not working
I have tried to just check the working live data by implementing delay in DB operations (For Example : When user enters the item details and tries to click the save button , user just returns to Item Listing Fragment and after delay of 3 Sec the item will be updated in the DB. After the updation the listview is not updated.)
Code :
Item Listing Fragment :
class ItemFragment : Fragment()

{

private lateinit var adapter : CustomCursorAdapter

private lateinit var databaseHelper : DatabaseHelper

private lateinit var binding : FragmentItemListBinding

private val itemViewModel : ItemViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreateView(inflater : LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState : Bundle?): View?
{
    binding = FragmentItemListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    setUpToolBar()

    updatedListView()

    setClickListeners()

}

private fun setUpToolBar()
{
    binding.toolbar.setTitle("Item Listing")
    binding.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.baseline_arrow_back_24)
    binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        activity?.finish()
    }
}

private fun onListItemClick(position: Int)
{
    val cursor = adapter.cursor

    if(cursor.moveToPosition(position))
    {
        val item = Item(cursor)

        val addOrEditItemFragment = AddOrEditItemFragment().apply {

            arguments = Bundle().apply {

                putInt("itemId", item.itemId)
            }
        }

        val fragmentContainer = if(configuration.isDeviceInLandScapeMode(resources)) R.id.fragmentB else R.id.fragmentA

        navigateToAddOrEditFragment(fragmentContainer ,addOrEditItemFragment)
    }
}

private fun navigateToAddOrEditFragment(fragmentContainer : Int, addOrEditItemFragment:Fragment)
{
    parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(fragmentContainer, addOrEditItemFragment,"addOrEditItemFragment")
        .addToBackStack("AddOrEditItemFragment")
        .commit()
}

private fun setClickListeners()
{

    binding.listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->

        onListItemClick(position)
    }

    if (configuration.isDeviceInLandScapeMode(resources))
    {
        binding.add.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    else
    {
        binding.add.setOnClickListener()
        {
            navigateToAddOrEditFragment(R.id.fragmentA,AddOrEditItemFragment())
        }
    }
}

private fun updatedListView()
{
    adapter = CustomCursorAdapter(requireContext(), null)

    binding.listView.adapter = adapter

    itemViewModel.itemsCursorLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { cursor ->

        println("Cursor  :   "+ cursor)

        adapter.changeCursor(cursor)
    }

    itemViewModel.fetchItems()
    }

}

Item View Model :
class ItemViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
{
private val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(application)

private val _itemsCursorLiveData = MutableLiveData<Cursor>()

val itemsCursorLiveData: LiveData<Cursor> get() = _itemsCursorLiveData


fun fetchItems()
{
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)
    {
        val cursor = databaseHelper.getItems()

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
        {
            _itemsCursorLiveData.postValue(cursor)
        }
    }
  }
}

Add or Edit Item Fragment :
class AddOrEditItemFragment : Fragment()
{
private lateinit var newItem : Item
private lateinit var imageIntentListener : ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
private val viewModel : ItemDetailsViewModel by viewModels()
private var binding : FragmentAddoredititemBinding ?= null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, 
savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
{
    binding = FragmentAddoredititemBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding?.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    setupItemDetails()

    setupObservers()

    handleDeviceBackButton()

    setOnButtonClickListeners()

    fragmentResultListeners()
}


private fun setupItemDetails()
{
    val itemId = arguments?.getInt("itemId") ?: -1
    if (itemId != -1)
    {
        setUpToolBar(true)
        viewModel.loadItem(itemId)

    }
    else {
        setUpToolBar(false)
        newItem = Item()
    }
}

private fun setupObservers()
{
    viewModel.item.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { item ->

        newItem = item

        binding?.editName?.setText(newItem.name)
        binding?.editPrice?.setText(newItem.price)
        binding?.editSku?.setText(newItem.sku)
        binding?.editdesc?.setText(newItem.desc)

        if (newItem.imageResource != Uri.EMPTY)
        {
            binding?.imageView?.setImageURI(newItem.imageResource)
        }
    }
    
}

private fun handleDeviceBackButton()
{
    val backPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true)
    {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed()
        {
            if((configuration.isDeviceInLandScapeMode(resources) && newItem.itemId != -1) || !configuration.isDeviceInLandScapeMode(resources))
            {
                showAlertDialogBox()
            }
            else
            {
                activity?.finish()
            }
        }
    }
    activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, backPressedCallback)
}

private fun setNavigationIcon()
{
    binding?.toolbar?.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.baseline_arrow_back_24)
    binding?.toolbar?.setNavigationOnClickListener {

        showAlertDialogBox()
    }
}

private fun setUpToolBar(isEdit : Boolean)
{
    if(isEdit)
    {
        binding?.toolbar?.title = "Edit Item"
        binding?.delete?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        setNavigationIcon()
    }
    else
    {
        binding?.toolbar?.title = "Add Item"
        if(!configuration.isDeviceInLandScapeMode(resources)) setNavigationIcon()
    }
}

private fun showAlertDialogBox()
{
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit ?")
    builder.setCancelable(false)
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ -> parentFragmentManager.popBackStack("AddOrEditItemFragment", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE) }
    builder.setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel() }
    val alertDialog = builder.create()
    alertDialog.show()
}

private fun saveItem()
{
    if(fieldEmptyOrNot())
    {
        newItem.apply {
            name = binding?.editName?.text.toString()
            price = binding?.editPrice?.text.toString()
            sku = binding?.editSku?.text.toString()
            desc = binding?.editdesc?.text.toString()
        }

        println("BEFORE SAVING :   "+newItem)

        viewModel.saveItem(newItem)

        parentFragmentManager.popBackStack()

    }
}

private fun setOnButtonClickListeners()
{
    binding?.imageView?.setOnClickListener{

        chooseImageGallery()
    }

    binding?.save?.setOnClickListener {

        saveItem()
    }

    binding?.delete?.setOnClickListener{

        deleteItem()
    }
}

private fun fieldEmptyOrNot():Boolean
{
    if (binding?.editName?.text.toString().isBlank())
    {
        binding?.editName?.error = "Please enter a name"
        return false
    }

    if (binding?.editPrice?.text.toString().isBlank())
    {
        binding?.editPrice?.error = "Please enter a price"
        return false
    }

    if(binding?.editSku?.text.toString().isBlank())
    {
        binding?.editSku?.error = "Please enter a SKU"
        return false
    }

    return true
}

private fun chooseImageGallery()
{
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {

        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "image/*"
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    }
    imageIntentListener.launch(intent)
}

private fun fragmentResultListeners()
{
    imageIntentListener = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            newItem.imageResource = result.data?.data as Uri
            activity?.contentResolver?.takePersistableUriPermission(newItem.imageResource, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            binding?.imageView?.setImageURI(newItem.imageResource)
        }
    }
}

private fun deleteItem()
{
    newItem.let { viewModel.deleteItem(it.itemId) }
    
    parentFragmentManager.popBackStack()
}

}
Item View Details View Model :
ItemDetailsViewModel(application : Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
{
private val _item = MutableLiveData<Item>()
val item: LiveData<Item> get() = _item


private val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(application)

fun loadItem(itemId: Int)
{
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)
    {
        val cursor = databaseHelper.getItemByID(itemId)

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            val loadedItem = Item(cursor)

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {

                _item.value = loadedItem
            }
        }
    }
}

fun saveItem(item: Item)
{
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch()
    {

        println("Thread  ${Thread.currentThread()}")

        delay(3000L)

        println("Running after delay")
        if (item.itemId != -1)
        {
            databaseHelper.updateItem(
                item.itemId, item.name, item.price, item.sku,
                item.imageResource, item.desc
            )
        }
        else
        {
            databaseHelper.addItems(
                item.name, item.price, item.sku,
                item.imageResource, item.desc
            )
        }
        
    }
}

override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    println("ItemDetailViewModel ViewModel destroyed")
}

fun deleteItem(itemId: Int)
{
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        databaseHelper.deleteItemByID(itemId)
    }
}

}
Kindly go through the code and Help me to resolve this

Does the logic for observing the itemsCursorLiveData get triggered?

Its triggered only for the first time ,but when the data changes in DB , it doesnot get triggered

There is a reason why it doesn't trigger a second time. Does the DB update the funnel properly?
